# Class to Activity passing ArrayList values

Tags: android

I am beginner in Android. I have saved entering values into db and then store them into `ArrayList`. I want to get all values in Activity but I can't pass it into constructor. How do I do that? Can somebody please help?

```
public String printTableData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME, null);
    if (cur.getCount() != 0) {
        cur.moveToFirst();
        do {
            row_values = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < cur.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                data = new ArrayList<String>();
                row_values = row_values + " || " + cur.getString(i);
            }
            Log.d("LOG_TAG_HERE", row_values);
            data.add(row_values);
        } while (cur.moveToNext());
    }
    return row_values;
}
```

Comment: remove ` data = new ArrayList<String>();` line from for loop and put outside of it(above "if{}" )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method to return the data

```
public ArrayList<String> printTableData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME, null);
    if (cur.getCount() != 0) {
        cur.moveToFirst();
        data = new ArrayList<String>();
        do {
            row_values = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < cur.getColumnCount(); i++) {

                row_values = row_values + " || " + cur.getString(i);
            }
            Log.d("LOG_TAG_HERE", row_values);
            data.add(row_values);
        } while (cur.moveToNext());
    }
    return data;
}
```

And then in your activity call this method

```
ArrayList<String> dataList = printTableData();
```

your `dataList` has all the data now.

This is assuming that this method is in your activity class. If its in your Helper class create an object of that helper class and then call this method from the object

Answer (score 0):

Its so simple and easy...There are so many ways to send and recieve data in activity.

1- Use Bundle to send and receive data in activity.

```
public ArrayList<String> printTableData() {
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME, null);
if (cur.getCount() != 0) {
    cur.moveToFirst();
    do {
        row_values = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < cur.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            data = new ArrayList<String>();
            row_values = row_values + " || " + cur.getString(i);
        }
        Log.d("LOG_TAG_HERE", row_values);
        data.add(row_values);
    } while (cur.moveToNext());
}
return data;
```

}

In your activity class:

```
ArrayList<String> data = printTableData();
```

now you can iterate loop on data.

Another way is:

In your first activity

```
ArrayList<String> myList = printTableData();
intent.putExtra("mylist", myList);
startActivity(intent, AnotherActivity.Class);
```

In your another activity:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("mylist");
```

Another way is to use Event Bus to send and receive data.
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus